# Connecting data and pop up in the map using D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to connect the data to the map and pop up on mouse hover. I used only 3-4 rows from dataset for testing..

http://jsfiddle.net/2emnt8m3/1/

Here is :

```
    d3.select("body").selectAll("path").each(function(d,i){
    state_id = d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("entity_id");
    title = d3.select(this).attr("title");
    });
```

when mouse hover on states or union territory, data of the crime would pop up.

Here is complete dataset I collected in json/js
http://pastebin.com/mZ6zc5CB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd convert your data to a `d3.map` for ease of lookup and then pull the data by the hovered element's id:

```
var m = d3.map(data, function(d) { return d.STATEUTS.toUpperCase(); }); 
var el=d3.select("body").selectAll("path")
.on("mouseover", function(d) {  
    var id = d3.select(this).attr('id');
    if (m.has(id)){      
        var d = m.get(id);
        //Display of Data on mouse hover        
        div.transition().duration(100).style("opacity", .75);      
        div.html( "<bold><br/>"+ d.STATEUTS +"</bold><br/>"+"<br/>"
            +"Assault : "+ d.Assault +"<br/>"
            +"Cruelty : "+ d.Cruelty +"<br/>"
            +"Dowry Death : "+ d.Dowry +"<br/>"
            +"Dowry Act : "+ d.Prohibition +"<br/>"
            +"Immoral : "+ d.Immoral +"<br/>"
            +"Importation of girl : "+ d.Importation +"<br/>"
            +"Insult : "+ d.Insult +"<br/>"
            +"Kidnapping,Abduction : "+ d.Kidnapping +"<br/>"
            +"Rape : "+ d.Rape +"<br/>"
            +"Total : "+ d.Total +"<br/>"
        )
        .style("left",(d3.event.pageX-50) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-132) + "px");  
    }
})
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2emnt8m3/3/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. How can I get different color for different states.

Comment: @Singh, you want the pop-up a different color for each state ? http://jsfiddle.net/2emnt8m3/4/

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. One last thing, I want to get the data on mouse hover to a particular STATE map and generate a pie chart , BUT I don't know how to get the data  from the STATE map. http://jsfiddle.net/2emnt8m3/14/

Comment: Would u mind helping me in this last one please... As i don't know how to get data on mouse hoverto a STATE and to generate PIE chart....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847482/need-help-on-pie-chart-transition-taking-data-on-mouse-hover-of-a-state-of-the-m